# Ajax Error: index.html:17 Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.sendAjax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

On running index.html on local host using xampp it gives error:
index.html:17 Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.sendAjax @ index.html:17onclick @ index.html:28

Here is index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Show Ajax</title>

<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
            document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;   
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'data.html');

};
function sendAjax(){
        xhr.send();
        document.getElementById('load').style.display = "none";

    }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Bring on ajax</h1>
<button id="load" onClick="sendAjax()">bring it</button>
<div id="ajax">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is data.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p> Hello I'm Ajax, came here on your request</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open the request inside the `readyState` handler, as that handler is only fired as the request is being made, after it's opened, you have to open the request before the `readyState` handler is called, but after it's defined, meaning outside the function, after it.

You should also generally create a new request object for each call to the `sendAjax` function, unless you have a very good reason not to do so

```
function sendAjax(){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;   
        }
    };

    xhr.open('GET', 'data.html');
    xhr.send();

    document.getElementById('load').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! you are right, i was opening request inside readystate, i simply putted it off the function and works fine now.
I appreciate it. :)